# 2013 workflow - update task list field with the ID (countertype)from another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a custom list with a 2013 workflow that creates a tan in a task list.  When a new item is created in this custom list, the ID field is the unique ID that I want to write to a field that I've added to the Workflow Task 2013 item that is created in the task list.  I'm trying to use the update item action but it isn't working.  I've done this in nintex many times,  but cannot get it to work with SP Designer 2013. Is this broken on SP Designer 2013?

Thanks for your help.